# CSS menu auto width - links with multiple words line breaking

Tags: css, hyperlink, html-lists

Here's a live demo for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6NQ/2/

On `ul#navigation ul`, if there is an explicit width, the links appear on their own "line" as intended. However, as the links have varying widths, I'd rather leave it as `"auto"` so the `<ul>` isn't really wide for lists with short content.

How can I prevent the link from line breaking, without setting an explicit width. If the link is one word, I get the desired effect, but with multiple words, the `<ul>` is only as wide as the longest word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ul#navigation li {
    white-space:nowrap; /* <-- ADDED */
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
```

If you want to shorten long lines add a `<br />` in the anchor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use non-breaking spaces. Instead of spaces in the link, use &nbsp;.

Comment: +1 I never thought of that! *THAT'S* why it's called a **non-breaking** space!

Comment: Haha yes, but the CSS solution is a bit more elegant.